# how to make the change_password template in flask-user to extend a different template based on user-roles

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i have this code for change_password.html in flask-user:

```
{% extends 'admin.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% from "flask_user/_macros.html" import render_field, render_submit_field %}
<h1>{%trans%}Change password{%endtrans%}</h1>

<form action="" method="POST" class="form" role="form">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field(form.old_password, tabindex=10) }}
    {{ render_field(form.new_password, tabindex=20) }}
    {% if user_manager.enable_retype_password %}
        {{ render_field(form.retype_password, tabindex=30) }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ render_submit_field(form.submit, tabindex=90) }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I would like the template to extend two different templates namely employee.html and admin.html based on user roles. that is if the user is an employee, then the template extends employee.html and admin.html is extended if the user is an admin. how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Jinja's documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#child-template) there must be only one `extends` statement, that should be placed on the top of the file. To overcome this limitation you may join your two templates into the one, and switch between them using `if` statement inside the new template.

Comment: thanks this helps. i was struggling with using `if` statements to try to switch between two `extends`.